# Не могу адаптировать код Matlab в Python

Tags: python, numpy, матрицы, matlab

подскажите, пожалуйста.
Код в матлаб:

```
 C = Ye'*Ye / (N-M+1);                
 [RHO,LAMBDA] = eig(C);
```

Код в пайтоне:

```
С = np.dot(Ye.T, Ye) / (N-M+1)
lamdba, rho = LA.eig(C)
```

Я использовал методы dot и matmul.
Размерность Ye 491x10, N 500, M 10.
Я использовал методы dot и matmul. Но размерность C в матлабе 10х10, а в пайтоне 491x10. Подскажите, пожалуйста, что делать?

Comment: Пример данных добавьте, пожалуйста. Какие размеры у матрицы `Ye` в матлабе?

Comment: Добавил, Ye 491x10,  N 500, M 10

Comment: Вы пишете что-то удивительное. `Ye=np.random.rand(491,10);print(Ye.shape);C=np.dot(Ye.T, Ye); print(C.shape)` -- печатает `(491, 10)` и `(10, 10)`. Размер `C` - 10 на 10.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Это не ответ, а расширенный комментарий.

Так как вы не дали свои данные, я попробовал ваш код на случайной матрице `Ye`.

```
import numpy as np

Ye = np.random.rand(491,10)
N=500
M=10

C = np.dot(Ye.T, Ye) / (N-M+1)
np.linalg.eig(C)
```

Python 3.9, работает, проверено.

Отредактируйте ваш вопрос, покажите весь код или дайте [минимальный воспроизводимый пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).